# DIV Not Displaying In Chrome & Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am very new to working with cross-browser HTML/CSS. I'm trying to create a page with DIVs that have embedded DIVs.

I want to create a page that looks something like this:

http://www.tennantco.com/am-en/equipment

Where I have a DIV with a background picture and also a "header" DIV within the DIV that contains a background-color and text. Something like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <a/>
        <div>
            <h3/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which is how the above referenced website seems to do it.

But I can't get it to work in Chrome & Firefox. It does work on IE8 (which is the version of IE - the only version - I need to support). The above referenced website does work in Chrome & Firefox, so I know I'm doing something wrong.

The problem is that on Chrome and Firefox the header part does not show up. I've created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/03ddL05k/

This is probably very simple, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I apologize for asking such an inane question.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your inline styles make this very difficult to debug.

Comment: @ray i agree. it started off easier to do it that way then kinda got out of hand.

Comment: @TJGrant that is **never** an easier or better way. You wrote your `css` code 3 times just for that fiddle.. You have separate "boxes" in jsfiddle for a reason.. Why don't you get it right and then we can help you out?

Answer (score 2):

You have `opacity: 0;` defined (inlined) for your anchor tags.

`opacity` specifies the transparency of an element. The value applies to the element as a whole, including its content, the element and its contained children as well. `0` is fully transparent, meaning invisible.

I updated your fiddle for your review http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/03ddL05k/4/.

Comment: Ha. So it only works in IE8 because IE8 doesn't support opacity?

Comment: Correct, for opacity in IE8, you would use `-ms-filter: alpha(opacity=xx);`.

Comment: thank you @ChrisYongchu. That solved my problem. I knew it was something simple.